# .NET 8 RC1 call method with UnsafeAccessorAttribute throw Internal CLR error

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I'm trying out a new .NET 8 feature to access a private field. Here's the code and project settings:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

var t = new Test();
var size = Caller.GetSize(t);

Console.WriteLine(size);

public class Caller
{
    [UnsafeAccessor(UnsafeAccessorKind.Field, Name = "_size")]
    public static extern int GetSize(Test c);
}

public class Test
{
    private int _size = 4;
}
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

But it throw exception:

```
Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)
   at Caller.GetSize(Test)
   at Program.<Main>$(System.String[])
```

MSBuild 17

Any idea's?

I expected console output: 4

Comment: Seem like the same issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92104